# next js and rgbk slider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, jsx

so i'm using next js 13 and when i route into another page and comeback to my homepage again
the slider which was made by my script.js doesn't render again  when i inspect i find that the script tag up on the all div which is the div that contain all of the pages
it jupes down to the bottom of the body tag

here is a video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U7Fxndd0zD4

i tried to put the script under the body tag but the next script tag always put it back into the body tag